# What are some SWT datagrids/tables?

Tags: eclipse, swt

I need to be able to display some data in Eclipse in a grid/table control... I need things like paging, multiple column sorting, column choosing, etc. There is an SWT Table and the [Nebula project has a grid in alpha](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/grid/grid.php).

Does what I need exist? 3rd party maybe? Doesn't have to be free, we can pay for the functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen those features implemented in a reusable widget that I can think of, they are more application-level features.

**Paging:**
If you were to use the JFace-type viewers (SWT Table or [Nebula Grid](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/grid/grid.php) both support this style of MVC architecture, as do some others mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115766/a-more-advanced-table-spreadsheet-swt-implementation)), it should be possible to implement paging in the content provider, just by setting some custom offset into your dataset and then refreshing the grid.

**Multiple Column Sorting:**
You can do this, it just needs an implementation of the correct table sorting interface. You get passed two rows to compare, and you can compare whichever columns you like in the sorting algorithm. Again though, the interface for actually choosing which columns to sort is down to you.

**Column Choosing:**
This requires a grid control with cell selection. Nebula is one, SWT Table isn't. If cell selection is available, this is just a matter of catching the correct selection event (clicking on a header probably) and iterating over your rows to select the correct cells.

Comment: NatTable does Mutliple Column Sorting (with the help of GlazedLists) and Column Choosing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the facilities of table presentation offered by the [BIRT plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/intro/), that is if you are really advance [table layout needs](http://java.sys-con.com/node/295339/print).
[image]
<sub>(source: [theserverside.com](http://www.theserverside.com/tt/articles/content/EclipseBRT/Images/templ_use.png))</sub>

(otherwise the classic SWT [TableViewer](http://www.richclient2.eu/2006_07_28/tableviewer-with-eclipse-32-sorter-filter-and-sort-indicator/) offers already some of the feature you are after [image]
<sub>(source: [richclient2.eu](http://www.richclient2.eu/wp-content/uploads/2006/07/table_fract.png))</sub>  )

Answer (score 1):

There is also a new "rising star" on the widget sky called "nattable 2.0". It is an opensource project and the development team is very responsive. You should take a look at nattable.org ...