# Java SWT muliline in list

Tags: java, list, swt

I got a `List`:

```
final List list = new List(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.MULTI );
```

Which I try to add text too including `"\n"`:

```
list.add("123 \n 1234");
```

The result is an list item with only the text

```
123 1234
```

in it but I want the result:

```
123
1234
```

How can I make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Native multi-lines are not supported in SWT list/table/tree (due to Windows limitations). You could use `TableViewer` with [owner-draw](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html#jfacetable_styledlabelprovider) but you will have all your rows with same hight (again, Windows thing). Or you could use some [alternative implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/115766/150166).